# Angular JS simple date comparator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a simple date comparator with AngularJS. Basically, I will have a list of coupons with both a dateStart and dateExpire field. I am looking to filter this list by comparing a user input searchStartDate and searchExpireDate with the dateStart and dateExpire of the coupon itself. What I have right now in the controller is:

```
    $scope.startDateFilter = function (coupon) {

        var filteredList = [];
        var searchStartDay = new Date().getDate();
        var searchStartMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        var searchStartYear = new Date().getYear();
        var startDate = new Date(coupon.dateStart).getDate();
        var startMonth = new Date(coupon.dateStart).getMonth();
        var startYear = new Date(coupon.dateStart).getYear();

        if (searchStartDay <= startDate && searchStartMonth <= startMonth && searchStartYear <= startYear)
            filteredList.push(coupon);

        if (searchStartMonth < startMonth && searchStartYear <= startYear)
            filteredList.push(coupon);

        if (searchStartYear < startYear)
            filteredList.push(coupon);

        return filteredList;
    }
```

This block is my custom filter for comparing startDate with the user input searchStartDate. However, this isn't working for me.

My view is:

```
 <tbody data-ng-repeat="coupon in activeList = (couponList | filter: {name: searchParent} | filter: startDateFilter) " data-ng-switch on="couponCollapse[$index]">
```

Does anyone know why I might be running into a problem here?

Comment: I would suggest implementing a custom filter to keep a better separation of concerns https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: I agree. Separation of concerns is one reason why angularjs is so attractive. See my answer for a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure date comparison since you already have a valid date object. Try this.

```
$scope.startDateFilter = function (coupon) {

        var filteredList = [];
        var searchStartDate = new Date();
        var startDate = new Date(coupon.dateStart);

        if (searchStartDate < startDate)
            filteredList.push(coupon);

        return filteredList;
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh I feel dumb, didnt know you could directly compare two date objects. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kh2xgxqSUtTUuDmXRI3d?p=preview). As long as you use `<input type="date"/>` you can use standard comparisons e.g., ==, =>, etc.

Custom Filter:

```
app.filter('dateRangeFilter', function() {
  return function(coupons, from, to) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < coupons.length; i++) {
      if(coupons[i].startDate >= from && coupons[i].endDate <= to)
        result.push(coupons[i]);
    }

    return result;
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Start Date:
  <input ng-model="sd" type="date" />
  <br/>End Date:
  <input ng-model="ed" type="date" />
  <br/>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="coupon in coupons | dateRangeFilter:sd:ed">
      {{ coupon.startDate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}} to {{ coupon.endDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh I see, do standard comparisons work with datetime-local inputs as well?